# loop through array to create image slider with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create an image carousel and I want the images to loop through the array. The code is clearly working because the "no click" alert shows but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is JS. I know the problem is most likely the if statement. I'm a beginner in JS and haven't quite understood how to code that bit properly. In some sort of pseudo code, it would ideally be "if btn is clicked, then show the next image".

```
let images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];
let img = images.length;
let x = 0;

function whenClicked(e) {

for (let i = 0; i < img; i++) {
if (x == 0) {
   document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = ++img;
} else alert("no click!")
}
}

const btnLeft = document.getElementById("btn-left");
const btnRight = document.getElementById("btn-right");


btnLeft.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);
```

And here HTML.

```
<div class="slide-container">

    <div class="slide" id="img1">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x" id="btn-left"  ></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x" id="btn-right" ></i>
    </div>



</div>
```

CSS.

```
.slide-container {

}

.slide {
height: 789px;
width: 100%; 

background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url(../img/img1.jpg);

}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url(../img/img2.jpg);
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
background-image: url(../img/img3.jpg);
}

#btn-left {
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
 }
#btn-right {
position: absolute;
left: 1380px;
top: 400px;
}
```

Suggestions on what to do to improve would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You are setting the background image of the div to the iterator integer op the array:
`document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = ++img;`
change to:
`document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/"+ images[i]+")"`
also: Remove the for loop. save the array index number of the current image and increase or decrease that number depending on that number. Then see if the number is greater then `images.length` or smaller then 0 and wrap around to 0 or images.length

Comment: Thanks @dehart! Could you explain what happens in that parenthesis please?

Comment: I would but as I was typing Emiel beat me to it. His code should work. I'll post what I had below

Answer (score 0):

You might be overcomplicating your approach. Try to keep track of which image is currently being shown and what image should be next. You are almost doing this, with I assume is your intent, with the `x` variable. This is a great way to select an image from the array by simply doing `images[x]`, which translates to `images[0]` at the start.

So if you want to develop a system which changes the background image of the slide, then your buttons would have to change the value of the `x` variable. Let's give that variable a more clear name, like `currentIndex` which represents the current index in the `images` array. Or to be clear, the current image we are seeing.

When your right button is clicked, you'll want the next image. The next images in the `images` array is `images[1]`. All you have to do is update the `currentImage` value with `+1` or `++` and select the next image with `images[currentIndex]` to get the next one.

Same goes for the left button which should remove 1 from the `currentImage` with either `-1` or `--` to go back one index in the `images` array. Then select the image the same way with `images[currentIndex]`.

Now for both these buttons you'll need to check if you go past the start or the end of the `images` array. `currentIndex` cannot be lower than 0 and with 3 images in the array, the `currentIndex` value should not be higher than `2`, since we are counting with `[0, 1, 2]` in the images array.

Below I've made an implementation of this system. I hope this is what you intended to make. If I haven't been clear or you have question, then don't hesitate to ask.

```
let images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];
let amountOfImages = images.length;
let currentIndex = 0;

const slide = document.getElementById("img1");
const btnLeft = document.getElementById("btn-left");
const btnRight = document.getElementById("btn-right");

function prevImage() {
  if (currentIndex > 0) { // Can't go lower than 0.
    currentIndex--;
    updateImage();
  }
}

function nextImage() {
  if (currentIndex < amountOfImages - 1) { // Can't go higher than the amount of images present.
    currentIndex++;
    updateImage();
  }
}

function updateImage() {
  slide.style.backgroundImage = images[currentIndex];
}

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", prevImage);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", nextImage);
```

Comment: Thanks @Emiel. The logic behind it is perfectly clear when someone explains it to me. I can't seem to figure out how to replicate it though. And I dont know why :) Also, I've tried implementing yout code and it's not working o.o the fuctions dont even start! HELP.

Comment: You're welcome, Grace. Be sure to put your script before the closing `</body>` tag so your HTML can be selected from JavaScript. Also check your developer console in your browser which will probably indicate an error if there is one.

Comment: No particular warning or error detected in the developer console. It just doesn't work. Yeah, script is just above the closing body tag. :)

Comment: My other guess is that you have multiple left and right buttons in your HTML in which case will only work for the first left and first right button. Make sure your slider HTML is exactly the same as you showed in your question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let currentImage = 0;
  let images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];

  function whenClicked(e) {
    if(e.target.id == 'btn-left') {
      currentImage--;
    } else {
      currentImage++;
    }
    if(currentImage > images.length-1) { 
      currentImage = 0; 
    }
    if(currentImage < 0) { 
      currentImage = images.length-1;
    }
    document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = url('img/'+images[currentImage]);
  }
```

Comment: Right click on the location of <div class="slide" id="img1"> on the page and click "Inspect". Look at the HTML in the Elements panel when you click the Left or Right button to see if it actually changes.